Which compounds are considered cis, trans isomers?
I tried doing my own research but cannot find a more detailed description for geometric isomerism.
Every example gives the following example, which I understand. 
However, I couldn't find any explanation about compounds like the following example
Are these cis trans isomers? Or doesn't cis trans isomerism doesn't apply to compounds like above?

There is plenty of serious information on-line if you know how to search for it. Maybe you find helpful this link [E and Z Notation For Alkenes (+ Cis/Trans)] (https://www.masterorganicchemistry.com/2016/11/03/alkene-nomenclature-cis-and-trans-and-e-and-z/ )
